# Session returns null on next page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, drop-down-menu

I have this code here in the home page :

```
protected void imgPronouns_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("ListOfQuestions.aspx");
    Session["type"] = "Pronouns";
}
```

However when I try to get the session in the next page , it shows that it is null when I debug  :

```
protected void dropTask()
{
   string test = (string)(Session["type"]); //null
   dropListTask.DataSource = daoTask.GetAll(); 
   dropListTask.DataTextField = "TaskName";
   dropListTask.DataValueField = "TaskID";
   dropListTask.Items.FindByText(test).Selected = true; 
   dropListTask.DataBind();
   dropListTask.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
}
```

Am I doing this in the correct way? Basically what I am trying to do is to assign the session value to drop down list on the next page. However the above code does not work.

Comment: what event handler calls into `dropTask`?

Comment: i put dropTask() in page load (!Page.IsPostBack)

Comment: set the session and then redirect

Comment: @PrashanthThurairatnam , i dun get what u meant

Comment: Session["type"] = "Pronouns";Response.Redirect("ListOfQuestions.aspx");

Comment: yeah bro i did that awhile ago , the error is still there

Comment: Can you debug? where does the error occur. As I mentioned if you set the session and then do a page redirect you must get the value for the session on the next page under Page_Load()

Comment: If you do not know how to debug this, then post all of your code and someone may debug it for you; otherwise it will be next to impossible to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Redirect AFTER setting Session - Redirect terminates callstack execution if you don't use the overload that allows you to pass a boolean in order to not do so.

```
Session["type"] = "Pronouns";
Response.Redirect("ListOfQuestions.aspx");
```